# Android custom transition from child to parent Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, back-button, android-navigation

I have 2 `Activities`. `ActivityA` is the `parent Activity` of `ActivityB`:

My `Manifest` file:

```
<activity
        android:name=".ActivityA"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityB"
        android:parentActivityName=".ActivityA"/>
```

I've changed the transition from `ActivityA` to `ActivityB`:

```
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_left_in, R.anim.push_left_out);
```

That works fine. But now I also want to change the transition when going back from `ActivityB` to `ActivityA`. In my `ActivityB` I override the method `finish()` like this:

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_right_in, R.anim.push_right_out);
}
```

The problem is that the `finish()` method is only called when the hardware back `Button` is pressed, but not when the "go back arrow" (top left corner of the screen) is pressed.

I also want the custom `transition` when that `Button` is pressed.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it by:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                  finish();
                  overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_right_in, R.anim.push_right_out);

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```